# Redirect subfolder index.php to subfolder root

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, subdomain, subdirectory

I have the following url I want redirect using the .htaccess file in root with Mod Rewrite. I have searched and found good examples for the index file in root, but not in subfolder.
This is what I have and what I need.
Thank you in advance for your help.

/folder1/index.php
/folder1/index.php/
to
http://www.example.com/folder1/

/folder2/index.php
/folder2/index.php/
to
http://www.example.com/folder2/

I was asked for only 2 hyperlinks so I removed part of the link on the examples above. I appreciate the shorter way because I have many folders.

Comment: I want this:  http://www.example.com/folder1/index.php  http://www.example.com/folder1/index.php/  to  http://www.example.com/folder1/

Comment: I'm not sure you question makes any sense. Do you want to run folder1/index.php but display only folder1/?

Comment: This is weird... I'm trying to format with linebreaks and it is impossible.  I want this:

Comment: http://www.example.com/folder1/index.php

Comment: http://www.example.com/folder1/index.php/

Comment: to http://www.example.com/folder1/

Comment: I dont' know, this editing box is crazy. It delete the (http) and removed the "/" at the end on the second example. I hope someone get the idea. I want to redirect the request for index.php in the subfolder to the subfolder root (example.com/folder1/) with a slash at the end. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your .htaccess file.

```
RewriteEngine On

Rewrite  ^/folder1/index.php$ /folder1/ [L]
<Directory folder1>
   DirectoryIndex index.php
</Directory>
```

Of course the index can be what every you want like newindex.php.

Comment: I'm sorry, this code won't work. I tested and change confg, no luck.

Comment: Could someone help me with this please?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To redirect /folder/index.php to /folder ,You can use :

```
RewriteEngine on


RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/index\.php$ /$1/ [NC,L,R]
```

This will redirect :

- /anyfolder/index.php

to

- /anyfolder/